# How to drop a percentage of rows where the column value is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have a `df` where a certain column has 50% missing values.

How can I drop let's say 10% of the rows which are missing values in respect to the column?

Basically how can I reduce the percentage of missing values of a column from 50% to 40%?

Input (50% of values are missing (6/12)):

```
         0
    0  1.0
    1  1.0
    2  NaN
    3  NaN
    4  NaN
    5  1.0
    6  NaN
    7  1.0
    8  NaN
    9  1.0
   10  NaN
   11  1.0
```

Output (40% of values are missing (4/10)):
We dropped the last 2 NaN rows with ID's of 8 and 10

```
         0
    0  1.0
    1  1.0
    2  NaN
    3  NaN
    4  NaN
    5  1.0
    6  NaN
    7  1.0
    9  1.0
   11  1.0
```

Comment: I want to reduce the percentage of missing values by a specified percentage. 50% missing values, drop 10% of those (which is 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the array with the indices with nan values in your column, use:

```
nan_indices = df.index[df['your_column'].isna()]
```

To drop, say, the first 20%, use:

```
df.drop(nan_indices[:int(len(nan_indices) * 0.2)])   #to create a new DataFrame, if you want to modify the original one, put inplace=True
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# find  NaN entries in your df
nanEntries = df[pd.isnull(df)].index.tolist()
# choose 10% randomly
dropIndices = np.random.choice(nanEntries, size = int(df.shape[0]*0.1))
# drop them
df.drop(dropIndices)
```